# how to create a dataframe from saved data, calculated in a function

Tags: python, function, dataframe

Hi I have these nested dictionaries and lists as my data. Here is an abstract of two matches.

```
 my_stats = [
 {'_id': 'GLEvHIL2020031419A', 'stats': 
 {'data': [
 {'area': 'B1', 'key': 'Lineouts', 'possession': 'against', 'second': 7, 'endSecond': 27, 
 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:43', 'Lineout Presentation': 'Scrappy', 'Lineout Errors': 'Lost'},
 {'area': 'D2', 'key': 'Lineouts', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 344, 'endSecond': 383, 'time': 
  '2020-03-14T12:53:43', 'Lineout Presentation': 'Goodball', 'Lineout Errors': 'Lost'},
 {'area': 'A1', 'key': 'Lineouts', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 354, 'endSecond': 358, 'time': 
  '2020-03-14T12:56:43', 'Lineout Errors': 'Lost'}]}},
 {'_id': 'HJSvMON2020031419A', 'stats': 
 {'data': 
 [{'area': 'C1', 'key': 'Kick Off', 'possession': 'against', 'second': 0, 'endSecond': 6, 'time': 
 '2020-03-14T12:00:06', 'Kick Off Fielded': 'Unsuccessful'},
 {'key': 'Passive Tackle', 'possession': 'against', 'second': 9, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:09', 
 'value': 9, 'subMetric': 3, 'rtp': []}, 
 {'area': 'D1', 'key': 'Rucks', 'possession': 'against', 'second': 9, 'endSecond': 19, 'time': '2020- 
  03-14T12:00:19'}, 
 {'area': 'D1', 'key': 'Lineouts', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 33, 'endSecond': 45, 'time': '2020- 
 03-14T12:00:45', 'Lineout Formations': '5 Man', 'Lineout Area Of Throw': 'Front', 'Lineout 
 Contested': 'Contested', 'Lineout Presentation': 'Scrappy', 'Lineout Errors': 'Lost', 'Maul Meters': 
 '5'}, 
 {'key': 'Neutral Tackle', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 45, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:45', 'value': 
 1, 'subMetric': 2, 'rtp': [{'key': 'Defender in Position', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 49, 
'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:49', 'value': 1, 'subMetric': None}]},
 {'area': 'D1', 'key': 'Rucks', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 47, 'endSecond': 50, 'time': '2020-03- 
 14T12:00:50'}, 
 {'key': 'Defender in Position', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 49, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:49', 
 'value': 1, 'subMetric': None, 'rtp': []}, 
 {'key': 'Passive Tackle', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 51, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:51', 'value':       
 7, 'subMetric': 3, 'rtp': [{'key': 'Defender in Position', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 53, 
 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:53', 'value': 7, 'subMetric': None}]}, 
 {'key': 'Tackle Assist', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 52, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:52', 'value': 
 8, 'subMetric': None, 'rtp': [{'key': 'Defender in Position', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 53, 
 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:53', 'value': 8, 'subMetric': None}]}, 
 {'key': 'Defender in Position', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 53, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:53', 
 'value': 8, 'subMetric': None, 'rtp': []}]}}]
```

I need to write a function where I calculate the Lineouts won per match and save the game name (_id) and the amount of Goodball, Scrappy and Drive lineouts per match. in order for me to create a dataframe to be able to create graphs.

The 1st problem was that not all the dictionaries with key : lineout has a 'Lineout Presentation' key. I overcame that with try: except:

```
Lineouts = []
Games = []
def Our_Lineouts_Won():
        global Lineouts
        Lineouts = (0)
        
        for l in my_stats:
            t=(l['stats']['data'])
            print(l['_id'])
            Games.append(str(l['_id']))
            
            for i in t:
                 
                 try:
                     if ((i['key']) == 'Lineouts' and (i['possession'])== 'for'and ((i[('Lineout 
                     Presentation')])==  'Off the Top'  or 'Scrappy' or  'Drive'  )):
          
                        
                        Lineouts += 1 
                        
                 except KeyError:
                    pass  

            #print(str(Lineouts))
            Lineouts.insert(str(Lineouts)) 

            #for Lineouts in my_stats:       
                        
                 
            Lineouts.append(Lineouts)
                    
            
            
        #Lineouts = (0) 
        #return Lineouts
    
        
Our_Lineouts_Won()

print (Games) 
print (Lineouts)
```

My desired outcome would be a dataframe with the game name (_id) followed by columns of calculated data (of which Goodball lineouts would be the 1st. )

I have tried appending the Lineouts to a list.

Please assist.

Comment: `global Lineouts; Lineouts = (0)` - what is that supposed to do?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. global Lineouts is supposed to add the data to outside the for loop. and I had to put Lineouts = 0 to let my for loop start at 0 for each game. There will probably be easier ways to do it. I am very new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

I cant believe it but I did it. Its the 1st big(for me) problem that I managed to figure out.

Here is how. I created a dictionary lpg... short for lineouts per game.
Then I appended all the _id to a list Games.

After that I went with try and except, to stop the code from breaking if no Lineout presentation was captured.

each lineout that met the criteria was added per game and saved under the variable L1.

And then I updated my empty dictionary with

lpg.update({games:L1})

an as you can see I created the dataframe off the dictionary with
df = pd.DataFrame(list (lpg.items())).

```
Lineouts = []
Games = []
lpg = {}
def Our_Lineouts_Won():
        global Lineouts
        global lpg
        Lineouts = (0)
        lpg = {}
        for l in my_stats:
            t=(l['stats']['data'])
            games = (l['_id'])
            Games.append(str(l['_id']))
            #print (games)
            
            for i in t:
                 
                 try:
                     if ((i['key']) == 'Lineouts' and (i['possession'])== 'for'and ((i[('Lineout Presentation')])==  'Off the Top'  or 'Scrappy' or  'Drive'  )):
            #if ((i['key']) == 'Lineouts' and (i['possession'])== 'for'and ((i[('Lineout Presentation')])==  'Off the Top'  or (i[('Lineout Presentation')])==  'Scrappy' or (i[('Lineout Presentation')])==  'Drive'  )):
                        
                         Lineouts += 1
                        
                 except KeyError:
                    pass  
            
            L1=(str(Lineouts))
            
            lpg.update({games:L1})
            
            
            
        
            
            Lineouts = (0)
               
            
            
        #print (lpg)   
             
       
Our_Lineouts_Won()


print (Games)
#print (Lineouts)
#print (lpg)

df = pd.DataFrame(list (lpg.items()))

print(df)
```